# Rust chrono::NaiveTime::parse_from_str() fails to parse PM

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

While parsing strings with Rust chrono::NaiveTime::parse_from_str(), it appears that parsing AM works but PM doesn't work (returns ParseErrorKind::Impossible).  Is there a reason for the following failure?

The first example `time_am` is a time string with AM that parses correctly.

The second example `time_pm` is a time string with PM that fails to parse.

```rust
fn main() {
    let time_am = chrono::NaiveTime::parse_from_str("08:30 AM", "%H:%M %p");
    println!(
        "time_am: {}",
        match time_am {
            Ok(time) => time.to_string(),
            Err(error) => error.to_string(),
        }
    );

    let time_pm = chrono::NaiveTime::parse_from_str("08:30 PM", "%H:%M %p");
    println!(
        "time_pm: {}",
        match time_pm {
            Ok(time) => time.to_string(),
            Err(error) => error.to_string(),
        }
    );
}
```

Result:

```
time_am: 08:30:00
time_pm: no possible date and time matching input
```

That error string corresponds to the following line in chrono `mod.rs`:

```rust
ParseErrorKind::Impossible => write!(f, "no possible date and time matching input"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself, shortly after posting the question.  The problem is  that the use of `%H` corresponds to 24-hour time.  I need to use `%I` for 12-hour time.